# Easy way to create a SOAP web service from a WSDL [any language]

Tags: web-services, language-agnostic, soap, wsdl

I'm looking for a simple solution to create (not consume) a SOAP web service from a WSDL file.  I'm not particular about the language and tools used, as long as it is easy (clear instructions, etc) to set up.  Automatic stubbing would be nice, but I could live without it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [SOAP UI](http://www.soapui.org/) you dont need a language or even app server.

Here is a blog that walks your through it:

1. [Setting up your project based on a wsdl](http://www.soapui.org/SOAP-and-WSDL/working-with-wsdls.html)
2. Then how to mock a service:  [Working with MockServices](http://www.soapui.org/Service-Mocking/mocking-soap-services.html)

It is truly one of the best free tools out there.